# ts this в функции внутри массива

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

в массиве функция обращающаяся к нему через `this`. мне vscode почему-то говорит что в такой функции `this` неявно `any` и подчёркивает его. как убрать сообщение об ошибке?

```
const q: [() => void, ...Array<iDestructible>] = [
  function () {
    for (let i = 1; i < this.length; this[i++].destroy()){}
  }
]
```

код работает, но тип не вычисляется. я както вообще могу заставить ts вычислить тип у `this`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface iDestructible {
  destroy: Function;
}
function qwe(this: iDestructible[]) {
    for (let i = 1; i < this.length; this[i++].destroy()) { }
  }
```

Comment: вернее будет [так](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgI7IN4Chm+QEwgGcwoBXBMALmQDEyRLgB7EHPQkqZgTxvsZgWbAL5YYDJqzQB3CAAowAC2BEaqANoBdAJSZ2uGMyjJ5AGwhhkwZAF5kARgDc15AB5ky1QDoLIAObKLl5EGsAA1OFa3pykFGDyOnoYyGIiQA), если согласен - отредактируй ответ и отметь его как принятый

Comment: @qwabra спасибо)